# android - Как удалить данные с сервера?

Tags: java, android

Мы с другом решили изучить что-то новое и попробовали со связки сервер-приложение. Друг создал все необходимое со своей стороны. Он создал вот эту ссылку

http://java.pareto-marketing.ru/showBD.php

где хранятся данные. Мне нужно через ссылку

http://java.pareto-marketing.ru/chat.php?action=delete

Удалить данные с сервера чтобы на той странице Json ответ был null. Мой код:

```
try {

        URL url = new URL("http://java.pareto-marketing.ru/chat.php?action=delete");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 

        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000); // ждем 10сек 

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); 

        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); 

        conn.connect(); 


    } 

    catch (Exception e) 

    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } 

    finally 

    {
        if (urlConnection != null)
    {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }        
    }
```

Я проверял по команде

```
finish();
```

после каждой строчки кода. Если поставить её после

```
conn.connect();
```

приложение не закрывается. Значит эта строчка не выполняется. Почему?

Comment: Может потому, что вылетает исключение? Для определения выполняется ли тот или иной код используйте отладчик.

Comment: @temq, не выполняется conn.connect();

Comment: пермишн в манифесте на интернет прописан?